# Recursive function not returning sum of object values

Tags: javascript

Why `sum` is `undefined`. What am I doing wrong?

```js
var testData1 = [{
  "name": "Doctors",
  "category": "Doctors",
  "subCategory": [{
    "name": "Likes",
    "category": "Likes",
    "subCategory": [{
      "name": "Visit",
      "category": "Visit",
      "subCategory": [{
        "name": "Charges",
        "category": "Charges",
        "subCategory": null,
        "val": 30
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Dislikes",
    "category": "Dislikes",
    "subCategory": [{
      "name": "Quality",
      "category": "Quality",
      "subCategory": [{
        "name": "Appointment",
        "category": "Appointment",
        "subCategory": null,
        "val": 50
      }, {
        "name": "Care",
        "category": "Care",
        "subCategory": null,
        "val": 70
      }, {
        "name": "Attentive ",
        "category": "Attentive ",
        "subCategory": null,
        "val": 90
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Neutral",
    "category": "Neutral",
    "subCategory": [{
      "name": "Professional ",
      "category": "Professional ",
      "subCategory": [{
        "name": "Ease",
        "category": "Ease",
        "subCategory": null,
        "val": 50
      }, {
        "name": "Competent ",
        "category": "Competent ",
        "subCategory": null,
        "val": 40
      }, {
        "name": "Availability",
        "category": "Availability",
        "subCategory": null,
        "val": 80
      }]
    }]
  }],
  "index": 6
}, {
  "name": "Service",
  "category": "Service",
  "subCategory": [{
    "name": "Likes",
    "category": "Likes",
    "subCategory": [{
      "name": "Environment",
      "category": "Environment",
      "subCategory": [{
        "name": "Professionalism ",
        "category": "Professionalism ",
        "subCategory": null,
        "val": 50
      }, {
        "name": "Room",
        "category": "Room",
        "subCategory": null,
        "val": 30
      }, {
        "name": "Parking",
        "category": "Parking",
        "subCategory": null,
        "val": 20
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "Availability",
      "category": "Availability",
      "subCategory": [{
        "name": "Competent ",
        "category": "Competent ",
        "subCategory": null,
        "val": 30
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Dislikes",
    "category": "Dislikes",
    "subCategory": [{
      "name": "Management",
      "category": "Management",
      "subCategory": [{
        "name": "Staff",
        "category": "Staff",
        "subCategory": null,
        "val": 50
      }, {
        "name": "Operations",
        "category": "Operations",
        "subCategory": null,
        "val": 70
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "Nurses",
      "category": "Nurses",
      "subCategory": [{
        "name": "Medicine",
        "category": "Medicine",
        "subCategory": null,
        "val": 30
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Neutral",
    "category": "Neutral",
    "subCategory": [{
      "name": "Serving",
      "category": "Serving",
      "subCategory": [{
        "name": "Took long time",
        "category": "Took long time",
        "subCategory": null,
        "val": 50
      }, {
        "name": "Rude",
        "category": "Rude",
        "subCategory": null,
        "val": 40
      }, {
        "name": "Seated",
        "category": "Seated",
        "subCategory": null,
        "val": 80
      }]
    }]
  }],
  "index": 16
}];

function addSum(data) {
  data.forEach(function(d, index) {
    if (Array.isArray(d.subCategory)) {
      return (0 + addSum(d.subCategory));

    } else {

      document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(d.val, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
      return d.val;
    }
  });
}
var sum = addSum(testData1);
alert(sum);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your return does not belong to `addSum`, it belongs to `forEach`, and that's why `addSum` returns nothing (undefined).
`Array.prototype.forEach` doesn't expect returning values, and cannot be used to calculate sum or something else.

You can utilize `Array.prototype.reduce` to achieve your result:

```
function sum(arr)
{
  return arr.reduce(function(a, b) { 
    return Array.isArray(b.subCategory) ? a + sum(b.subCategory) : a + b.val;
  }, 0);
}

sum(testData1);
```

Or using ECMAScript 6 arrow functions:

```
var sum = arr => arr.reduce((a, b) => Array.isArray(b.subCategory) 
    ? a + sum(b.subCategory) 
    : a + b.val, 0);
```

Working [JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/n985d7a6/1/).

Answer (score 2):

From [`.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) you can't return value, that's why you get `undefined`, for this case more suitable [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method

```
function addSum(data) {
  return data.reduce(function (p, c) {
    return p + (Array.isArray(c.subCategory) ? addSum(c.subCategory) : c.val);
  }, 0);
}
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/x2vvz98f/1/)

or if you want use `.forEach` you can do it like this

```
function addSum(data) {
  return function sum(data, result) {
    data.forEach(function (element) {
      result = Array.isArray(element.subCategory) 
        ? sum(element.subCategory, result)
        : result + element.val;
    });

    return result;
  }(data, 0);
}
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/x2vvz98f/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You can't return from your foreach, only from your function.  Here's a working version of your function:

```
function addSum(data,tot) {
  tot = tot || 0;
  data.forEach(function(d, index) {
    if (Array.isArray(d.subCategory)) {
      tot = addSum(d.subCategory, tot);
    } else {
      tot += parseInt(d.val);
      document.write('<pre>' + d.val + ' - ' + tot + ' </pre>');
    }
  });
  return tot;
}
```

and a jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/mckinleymedia/uk5njxnp/

I agree that this should be simplified to a reduce function, but I thought it would also help to see how to modify what you did to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Return in the foreach function is for the callback and does not return from the `addSum()` function. Foreach callback return will not help in this case. Instead using some external variable for keeping the sum will do the trick.

The updated code below defines a variable `sum` inside the `addSum()` function and the return value of recursive call is added to it. The function will now return the calculated sum at the end.

```js
var testData1 = [{
  "name": "Doctors",
  "category": "Doctors",
  "subCategory": [{
    "name": "Likes",
    "category": "Likes",
    "subCategory": [{
      "name": "Visit",
      "category": "Visit",
      "subCategory": [{
        "name": "Charges",
        "category": "Charges",
        "subCategory": null,
        "val": 30
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Dislikes",
    "category": "Dislikes",
    "subCategory": [{
      "name": "Quality",
      "category": "Quality",
      "subCategory": [{
        "name": "Appointment",
        "category": "Appointment",
        "subCategory": null,
        "val": 50
      }, {
        "name": "Care",
        "category": "Care",
        "subCategory": null,
        "val": 70
      }, {
        "name": "Attentive ",
        "category": "Attentive ",
        "subCategory": null,
        "val": 90
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Neutral",
    "category": "Neutral",
    "subCategory": [{
      "name": "Professional ",
      "category": "Professional ",
      "subCategory": [{
        "name": "Ease",
        "category": "Ease",
        "subCategory": null,
        "val": 50
      }, {
        "name": "Competent ",
        "category": "Competent ",
        "subCategory": null,
        "val": 40
      }, {
        "name": "Availability",
        "category": "Availability",
        "subCategory": null,
        "val": 80
      }]
    }]
  }],
  "index": 6
}, {
  "name": "Service",
  "category": "Service",
  "subCategory": [{
    "name": "Likes",
    "category": "Likes",
    "subCategory": [{
      "name": "Environment",
      "category": "Environment",
      "subCategory": [{
        "name": "Professionalism ",
        "category": "Professionalism ",
        "subCategory": null,
        "val": 50
      }, {
        "name": "Room",
        "category": "Room",
        "subCategory": null,
        "val": 30
      }, {
        "name": "Parking",
        "category": "Parking",
        "subCategory": null,
        "val": 20
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "Availability",
      "category": "Availability",
      "subCategory": [{
        "name": "Competent ",
        "category": "Competent ",
        "subCategory": null,
        "val": 30
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Dislikes",
    "category": "Dislikes",
    "subCategory": [{
      "name": "Management",
      "category": "Management",
      "subCategory": [{
        "name": "Staff",
        "category": "Staff",
        "subCategory": null,
        "val": 50
      }, {
        "name": "Operations",
        "category": "Operations",
        "subCategory": null,
        "val": 70
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "Nurses",
      "category": "Nurses",
      "subCategory": [{
        "name": "Medicine",
        "category": "Medicine",
        "subCategory": null,
        "val": 30
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Neutral",
    "category": "Neutral",
    "subCategory": [{
      "name": "Serving",
      "category": "Serving",
      "subCategory": [{
        "name": "Took long time",
        "category": "Took long time",
        "subCategory": null,
        "val": 50
      }, {
        "name": "Rude",
        "category": "Rude",
        "subCategory": null,
        "val": 40
      }, {
        "name": "Seated",
        "category": "Seated",
        "subCategory": null,
        "val": 80
      }]
    }]
  }],
  "index": 16
}];

function addSum(data) {
   sum = 0; 
  data.forEach(function(d, index) {
    if (Array.isArray(d.subCategory)) {
      sum += (0 + addSum(d.subCategory));

    } else {

      document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(d.val, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
      sum += d.val;
    }
  });

  return sum;
}
var sum1 = addSum(testData1);
alert(sum1);
```